# All possible combinations of Three-valued logic values

Tags: haskell, three-valued-logic

Is there an algorithm to lead all possible combinations of given amount of three-valued logic values?

For example, `F(2)` should return this list:

```
t t
t u
t f
u t
u u
u f
f t
f u
f f
```

The function would look like this (in Haskell):

```
data Tril = FALSE | NULL | TRUE

all :: Int -> [[Tril]]
all amount = ???

all1 :: [Tril]
all1 = join (all 1)

all2 :: [(Tril, Tril)]
all2 = map (\[f, s] -> (f, s)) (all 2)

all3 :: [(Tril, Tril, Tril)]
all3 = map (\[f, s, t] -> (f, s, t)) (all 3)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this very simply as a list comprehension:

```
all2 = [ (v1, v2) | v1 <- [FALSE, TRUE, NULL], v2 <- [FALSE, TRUE, NULL] ]
```

You can write it equivalently as a monadic do-block:

```
all2 = do
  v1 <- [FALSE, TRUE, NULL]
  v2 <- [FALSE, TRUE, NULL]
  return (v1, v2)
```

And that gives us an idea for how we can write the variable-size one:

```
all 0 = [[]] -- Note: Empty list with one empty item.
all n = do
  v  <- [FALSE, TRUE, NULL]
  vs <- all (n-1)
  return (v:vs)
```

As it turns out — and this is slightly mind-bending — this is the net effect of the `replicateM` function. It takes a monadic action, does it N times, and gathers the results together.

```
all n = replicateM n [FALSE, TRUE, NULL]
```

Answer (score 4):

`replicateM` does exactly that:

```
> import Control.Monad
> replicateM 2 [1,2,3]
[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]
```

Hence,

```
all :: Int -> [[Tril]]
all amount = replicateM amount [FALSE,NULL,TRUE]
```

I'd suggest to pick anouther name, since `all` is already taken by `Prelude.all`.